# Geometrical Isomerization

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

Can you explain to me:

- What are Cis-Trans, E-Z and Syn-Anti Isomerization?
- What is the difference between them?
- How many functional groups is cis-trans isomerism applicable to?

I  know mostly about cis trans and E-Z but have no idea about syn- anti isomers. Correct me if needed: I think cis and trans isomers respectively occur when identical atoms or groups are on the same or opposite side of the double bond respectively. E and Z isomers are for trans and cis in complex cases where more functional groups are involved.

Also, I couldn't follow the Wikipedia Link.

Comment: Syn and anti are used more commonly in case of addition to an unsaturated compounds not to denote the actual compounds.

Comment: see this [earlier answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20372/stereo-isomerism-syn-anti/20374#20374)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*cis* and *trans* are older notations that express roughly same concept of *E* and *Z*.

Explicitly, E and Z have absolute meaning and are assigned based on precedent, where the Z is assigned to the case where the highest priority substituents are on the same side of the alkene/double bond and *E* being opposite.  These notations explicitly refer to a pair wise relationship.  It is not normally said '... the group *E* to the ...'

*cis* and *trans* refer to substituents of context, with *cis* being substituents on the same side of the alkene/double bond, and *trans* being opposite.  Frequently these refer to the most important nomenclaturally, but not always.  Additionally *cis* and *trans* are used in discussions such as '...the group *trans* to the ...' describing a relation of one object relative to the other.  *cis* and *trans* are no longer considered IUPAC-correct nomenclature, but still have some usage for descriptive discussion.

Comment: what is syn anti that is my main question

Comment: Perhaps then, those terms should be first in your list of 'difference between' items.  Ron's comment contains a post to an answer which covers syn and anti.